# Duplicating web content for several pages

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I'm using Liferay CE 6.1 ga3, I finished developing themes + structures + templates for my pages now this is my problem:

I have to create several empty pages for the writers to fill content, I'm wondering if there is any manipulation to create pages with empty web content (only structure + template specified) so the writer have just to log and and edit the content for exp:

I have 80 pages that have header + product description + footer I have to create the 3 web contents empty for every page that is very exhausting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard to implement custom code to do this. As a starting point I recommend the [7cogs sample code](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-). You might need some adoption to newer API versions, but in general I see it as the easiest way to learn about Liferay's API.